# I am using ISOCRA drag and drop plugin with asp.net gridview. How to maintain state of rows between the postbacks?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

In a form there are few textboxes and a button, on a button click textbox values are added to gridview as a row.

user can drag and drop the rows to change the postion of the rows in the grid.

I need to maintan the state of rows(position) between the postbacks.

How I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the server with ajax each time the rows position change. Add an order column to your data and change the order in the server when such ajax call arrives. In each postback bind the grid again occording to the order column.